mistheorize, is it an actual word?
I wonder if the word “mistheorize” is a word that native speakers are familiar with and use. I looked it up in various dictionaries, and the only dictionary containing the word is wiktionary.

English is very flexible in allowing you to add prefixes and suffixes almost arbitrarily, as long as the base word is the appropriate type. Dictionaries can't be expected to list all possible combinations. So the notion of "actual word" is very fuzzy -- if the combination makes sense, it's usually a word.

This is indeed a rare word and is not in major dictionaries.  Wiktionary defines it:

to theorize incorrectly

Google Books, however, has quite a  number of pages among which
Kulchur, published in 1964, may be one of the earliest books with this
usage.

Thank you. Your reponse helped me a lot.
